# Example where U is connected with distance d2, but not with distance d1.

Tags: real-analysis

Michael Watson asked this  yesterday

"I have metric space E and $d_1$ and $d_2$ are two different metrics on E with the property that for all x∈E and all ε > 0, there exists δ>0,
such that $d_1$(x,y)< δ implies that $d_2$(x,y)< ε. Let U ⊂ E."

This got me thinking about connectedness. It would be possible to show that if U is connected with $d_1$, then it's also connected with $d_2$. But it would be really interesting to see if there was an example of distances $d_1$ and $d_2$ where U is connected with $d_2$  but not with $d_1$. I can't think of any at the moment. Maybe like if there was a discrete metric and some other metric in R?

If $d_1$ is discrete metric and if $d_2$ is |x-y| with S = subset of R, say just some inverval like [-1,1]? Would this work?

Comment: @kobe I rephrased the question to make more sense. Basically I can't think of an example where this is true.

Comment: @Kobe If assume U is not conencted with d2 then it is disconnected, so the union of 2 disjoint open sets. But if we look at Michael Watson's old question it says if U is open with d2 then it is also open with d1. So this would show that d1 is not connected, which is a contradiction. So, this is possible, and there should be an example, but I can't think of one

Comment: You're right, I'm mixing up the indices. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Kobe no problem! If you happen to think of an example let me know! I'm thinking about using a discrete metric and some other metric in R. Don't know if this will work to find U subset of E (metric space) where d2 is connected but not d1

Comment: Hello did you come up with an example? I cannot think of one